# Android Firebase Query StartAt()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a query in my android app and having some trouble. My database will eventually have hundreds or thousands of poll objects. I would like to get about 20 at a time and once I am done with those 20 I would get the next 20. I can get the first 20 easily but when I try to use `startAt()` the query just doesn't get anything.

Here is my code:

```
pollQuery = rootRef.child(getString(R.string.poll_ref)).startAt(lastPollFromQuery).orderByChild(getString(R.string.timestamp_ref)).limitToFirst(numPollsToLoad);
```

I have tried using an `Integer position` for `lastPollFromQuery` and am currently using a `String` (the key of a poll object). I have also shuffled around the `startAt()` and `orderByChild()` but that didn't do much.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to pass in both the timestamp and the key from the last poll. Say that you are going from the first page to the second page, then you need to know the timestamp and key of the last poll of page 1.

```
pollQuery = rootRef.child(getString(R.string.poll_ref))
    .orderByChild("timestamp")
    .startAt(timestampFromLastPollOfPage1, keyFromLastPollOfPage1)
    .limitToFirst(numPollsToLoad);
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just using the timestamp and not the key and it works the same.

Comment: That will indeed work as long as your timestamps are unique. Keep in mind that (as you have more users) chances of timestamp collisions will increase, making the key the only distinguishing factor.